# calabash-ios rotate throws launcher/run_loop error

Tags: ruby, calabash-ios

I'm trying to use the rotate funktion to bring the app into the landscape view. In the Console that works just fine like:

- rotate(:right)
- rotate(:left)
- rotate :right
- rotate :left

They work without a problem, however as soon as i try them through my custom step or the original step definition i get the following error message:

the current launcher must be active and be attached to a run_loop (ArgumentError)

Since i couldn't find anything regading the error message or the rotate command that would refer to this, i ask here if anyone knows how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
Thx for the advice alannichols however i'm already using the following commands to execut it:
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 4s (9.1)' bundle exec cucumber
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 4s (9.1)' bundle exec calabash-ios console

I use the calabash version 0.17.1 and xcode 7.1

**EDIT2:**
The content of my 01_launcher.rb is as follows:

```
require 'calabash-cucumber/launcher'
require 'run_loop'

# You can find examples of more complicated launch hooks in these
# two repositories:
#
# https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/support/01_launch.rb
# https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app/blob/master/CalWebViewApp/features/support/01_launch.rb

module Calabash::Launcher
  @@launcher = nil

  def self.launcher
    @@launcher ||= Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.new
  end

  def self.launcher=(launcher)
    @@launcher = launcher
  end
end

Before('@reset_app_btw_scenarios') do
  ENV['RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS'] = '1'
  start_test_server_in_background
end
```

Comment: One thing to check would be to run the console using bundle exec ..., to check it's using the same version of calabash as your automated tests. (If you aren't already)

Comment: What does your 01_launch.rb look like?  I seems like you are trying to rotate before the app is controlled by instruments.